# setting CSS class to selected ASP.NET Listview Item

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, listview

I have a listview which I want highlight the items on click. 
Using the below code, I could set the CSS class. But the foreach loop doesn't clear the css class set before.

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView2" runat="server" SelectedIndex="0" onitemcommand="ListView2_ItemCommand">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel8" runat="server" CssClass="left-listitem-div">
            <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" AlternateText="User Icon" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("UserType").ToString() == "AD_USER" ? "Images/icons/ldapuser32px.png" : "Images/icons/user32px.png"  %>'  CssClass="list-group-icon" />
            <asp:Label ID="ListUserID" runat="server"  Text ='<%#Eval("UserID") %>' CssClass="list-group-id" style="display:none;" />
            <asp:LinkButton ID="ListFullName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("FullName") %>' CssClass="list-group-name" CommandName="select" CommandArgument = '<%# Eval("UserID") %>'  Font-Underline="False" ForeColor="Black" Width="130" Height="30" />
            <asp:Label ID="ListUserName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("UserName") %>' CssClass="list-group-username" style="display:none;"  />
            <asp:Label ID="ListUserType" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("UserType") %>' CssClass="list-group-usertype" style="display:none;"  />
            <asp:Label ID="ListUserEnabled" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Enabled") %>' CssClass="list-group-enabled" style="display:none;"  />
            <asp:Label ID="ListUserDescription" runat="server" Text ='<%#Eval("Description") %>' CssClass="list-group-descri" style="display:none;" />
        </asp:Panel>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

The Codebehind is below. 
I used SelectedItemTemplate, but Listview selectedIndex is not changing. 
If I set the selectedIndex on ItemCommand event, Its affecting only at the next postback.

```
protected void ListView2_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.FindControl("Panel8") != null && e.Item.FindControl("Panel8") is Panel)
    {
        foreach (ListViewItem li in ListView2.Items)
        {
            Panel lipp = (Panel)e.Item.FindControl("Panel8");
            lipp.CssClass = "left-listitem-div";
        }
        Panel pp = (Panel)e.Item.FindControl("Panel8");
        pp.CssClass = "left-listitem-div selected";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, don't change the event, because you use commandEventargs.
Just set the SelectIndex of the listview and then change the css for that item.

```
protected void ListView2_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        (sender as ListView).SelectedIndex = e.Item.DataItemIndex;
        (e.Item.FindControl("Panel8") as Panel).CssClass += "SelectedCss";
    }
```

In the loop you alwas refer to the currently selected item, that's your problem.
Change the loop to this: --> **li**

```
foreach (ListViewItem li in ListView2.Items)
    {
        Panel lipp = (Panel)li.FindControl("Panel8");
        lipp.CssClass = "left-listitem-div";
    }
```

Comment: Hi, 
I have tested it. The selected style-setting works perfectly. 
But, the one inside foreach loop (resetting the style for other items) is not at all working.